# Get "Assertion failed" error when trying to calculate a 3 channels color histogram using calcHist by openCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, assertion

So I have a function to create a 3 channels histogram in Lab space. I use cv2.calcHist to calculate the histogram.

Here is my function:

```
def create_Lab_hist(img, bin_size=[2, 5, 5]):
    imgLab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2Lab)
    hist = cv2.calcHist([imgLab], [0, 1, 2], None, bin_size, [0, -127, -127, 100, 127, 127])
    histN = hist/np.sum(hist)
    histTensor = torch.from_numpy(histN)
    return histTensor
```

When I try to run the code with it, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anatolyryabchenko/Desktop/Projects/PitchEye/colorCluster.py", line 160, in <module>
    histArray = create_hist_array(imgArray, hist_builder=create_Lab_hist)
  File "/Users/anatolyryabchenko/Desktop/Projects/PitchEye/colorCluster.py", line 121, in create_hist_array
    histTensor = hist_builder(img)
  File "/Users/anatolyryabchenko/Desktop/Projects/PitchEye/colorCluster.py", line 113, in create_Lab_hist
    hist = cv2.calcHist([imgLab], [0, 1, 2], None, bin_size, [0, -127, -127, 100, 127, 127])
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-p3unqtkr/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp:202: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ranges[i] && ranges[i][0] < ranges[i][1] in function 'histPrepareImages'
```

The rest of the code should be ok, since when I substitute create_Lab_hist with similar function but for one channel, everything works well.

I also saw there were many similar issues with calcHist, and in fact it is reasonable since the error message is non-informative at all. It would be nice to make this question a little hub where all the answers relative to this issue are given

Comment: Looks like I needed to write ranges as a list of 2 lists. However, now I am getting a new error:
SystemError: <built-in function calcHist> returned NULL without setting an error

Comment: I looked at all the possible documentation and did not see that this function was used for all three image channels at once. Maybe you should use it for each channel separately, and then combine the arrays

Comment: crackanddie Thank you for your response. I previously saw on stackoverflow or somewhere else that calcHist can be used for an arbitrary number of channels. Moreover, if I use for different channels separately I lose the information about the joint distribution (which I need!).

Comment: One another thing I found is that even though ranges for L/a/b channels are documented to be [0,100], [-127, 127], and [-127, 127] respectively, it seems that documentation is wrong. When I calculate the histograms separately, the bins are non-zero in range [0,255], [0,255], [0,255]. I saw it was sometimes the source of the error, however changing it in my case didn't solve the issue.

Comment: i did some tests and all failed. Here's what I came up with: ```cv2.calcHist([imgLab, imgLab, imgLab], [0, 1, 2], None, [256, 256, 256], [[0, 127], [27, 100], [127, 227]])``` but it doesn't work anyway. I saw that you should pass array as first argument as you can see at my example, but it gives the same error. So I really do not know what to do